# PLSQL code isn't inserting into my inventory/transaction tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, logic

The code runs successfully but doesn't push any of the data into the tables. I've tried a bunch of things but they either break the code or return the same result.

```
ACCEPT v_idno PROMPT 'Enter the IDNO: ';
ACCEPT v_itemname PROMPT 'Enter the Item Name: '
ACCEPT v_price PROMPT 'Enter the Price: '
ACCEPT v_onhand PROMPT 'Enter the Onhand amount: '

DECLARE
    v_idno                  invent.idno%TYPE := &v_idno;
    v_itemname              invent.itemname%TYPE := '&v_itemname';
    v_price                 invent.price%TYPE := &v_price;
    v_onhand                invent.onhand%TYPE := &v_onhand;
    v_code                  transac.transaccode%TYPE;
    v_transac               transac.transaction%TYPE;

    CURSOR addinven IS
        SELECT invent.idno, itemname, price, onhand, transaccode, transaction
        FROM   invent, transac
        WHERE  v_idno = invent.idno;

BEGIN
    OPEN addinven;
    LOOP
        FETCH addinven INTO v_idno, v_itemname, v_price, v_onhand, v_code, v_transac;
        EXIT WHEN addinven%NOTFOUND;

        INSERT INTO invent
        (invent.idno, itemname, price, onhand)
        VALUES
        (v_idno, v_itemname, v_price, v_onhand);

        v_transac := v_price * v_onhand;

        INSERT INTO transac
        (transac.idno, transaction)
        VALUES
        (&v_idno, v_transac);

        UPDATE invent
        SET invent.idno = v_idno, itemname = 'v_itemname', price = v_price, onhand = v_onhand
        WHERE v_idno = invent.idno;

        UPDATE transac
        SET transac.idno = v_idno, transaction = v_transac
        WHERE v_idno = transac.idno;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE addinven;
END;
/
```

Also how would I go about displaying transactions ran through PLSQL code to output the before and after sales? Been held up on this for days...

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( string_to_output );` to output a value. You may need to use `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;` before the PL/SQL block to get it to display the value to the console.

Comment: I had tried that unfortunately.

Comment: @JBen, So you saying DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE displayed value you expected? Another thing, Did you try debugging it? I think if you debug you will find where is the problem.

Comment: Well I tried placing the & in front of multiple variables with VERIFY on and all of the outputs were as they should've been, but none were placed into their respective tables. You're saying just have it echo out what I think it should be?

Comment: @JBen then put commit at the end. You were checking from different session.  Just add           commit;

Comment: @JBen Not just echo. Debug it line by line. You can use Toad for it. Toad in debugging mode will show you execution and value at the time of execution.

Comment: @JBen - That is the reason you should handle exceptions. Also you can debug on SQL Developer

Answer (score 1):

add commit at the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a logical one. It seems like your program is executing stuff but it's not applying the changes you think it is, so that's why you're not seeing the data you expect.

If we look at your code, you start by accepting some user input:

```
ACCEPT v_idno PROMPT 'Enter the IDNO:';
ACCEPT v_itemname PROMPT 'Enter the Item Name:'
ACCEPT v_price PROMPT 'Enter the Price:'
ACCEPT v_onhand PROMPT 'Enter the Onhand amount:'
```

You then assign this input to some local variables.

```
DECLARE
v_idno                  invent.idno%TYPE := &v_idno;
v_itemname              invent.itemname%TYPE := '&v_itemname';
v_price                 invent.price%TYPE := &v_price;
v_onhand                invent.onhand%TYPE := &v_onhand;
v_code                  transac.transaccode%TYPE;
v_transac               transac.transaction%TYPE;
```

Presumably what you want to do is apply the user input values to your tables. The problem is, your cursor FOR LOOP inserts into the local variables you've just populated:

```
    FETCH addinven INTO v_idno, v_itemname, v_price, v_onhand, v_code, v_transac;
```

So of the two inserts, this creates a duplicate record (presumably no primary on `idno`)

```
INSERT INTO invent
(invent.idno, itemname, price, onhand)
VALUES
(v_idno, v_itemname, v_price, v_onhand);
```

... and this does create a new record because it references the substitution value of `&v_idno`

```
INSERT INTO transac
(transac.idno, transaction)
 VALUES
 (&v_idno, v_transac);
```

... but the calculated value is derived from the existing values so that isn't right `v_transac := v_price * v_onhand;`

The two update statements overwrite the existing records with the same values, except for `invent.itemname` which is set to the string literal `'v_itemname'`.

So, not sure what business rules you'e trying to implement but you need separate variables for your cursor and your user input. There's a couple of ways you can do this. One is to define a variable based on the cursor:

```
    CURSOR addinven IS
       SELECT invent.idno, itemname, price, onhand, transaccode, transaction
       FROM invent, transac
       WHERE v_idno = invent.idno;
    l_rec addinven%rowtype; 
  BEGIN
```

Fetch like this: `fetch addinven into lrec;`

Reference like this: `lrec.idno = invent.idno`

Alternatively use an implicit cursor for your loop:

```
for lrec in (SELECT invent.idno, itemname, price, onhand, transaccode, transaction
             FROM invent
                  join transac
                   on transac.idno = invent.idno
             WHERE v_idno = invent.idno)
loop
```

No need for OPEN, FETCH, CLOSE or EXIT. It's all done for you. Incidentally you need to join `invent` and `transac`. At the moment you have a Cartesian product of the two tables, and that's probably not what you want either.